# Symfony: Datetime form type with rfc 3339 string input

Tags: php, forms, symfony, datetime

I'm trying to use a datetime type

```
    $builder->add('start_date', 'datetime', array(
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'input'  => 'string'
    ));
```

my form date format is RFC 3339

```
    [start_date] => '2016-01-04T16:01:25+00:00'
```

Error

```
    The parsed date was invalid, The separation symbol could not be found, Unexpected data found., Unexpected data found., Unexpected data found., Unexpected data found., Unexpected data found., Data missing
```

seems that datetime type is only expecting date as string with format `2016-01-04 16:01:25` and this format can't be changed from the form type configs

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateTimeType.php#L171

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToStringTransformer.php#L68

wondering if thats the desired behavior or an issue

***Note***

both `format` and `date_format` options will work on the view data rather than the input data.

***stack trace***

```
at DateTimeToStringTransformer ->reverseTransform ('2016-01-04T16:01:25+0000') 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ReversedTransformer.php at line 46   + 
at ReversedTransformer ->transform ('2016-01-04T16:01:25+0000') 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php at line 1087   + 
at Form ->modelToNorm ('2016-01-04T16:01:25+0000') 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php at line 352   + 
at Form ->setData ('2016-01-04T16:01:25+0000') 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php at line 57   + 
at PropertyPathMapper ->mapDataToForms (array('start_date' => '2016-01-04T16:01:25+0000')), object(RecursiveIteratorIterator)) 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php at line 386   + 
at Form ->setData (array('start_date' => '2016-01-04T16:01:25+0000')) 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php at line 478   + 
at Form ->initialize () 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php at line 226   + 
at FormBuilder ->getForm () 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php at line 40   + 
at FormFactory ->create ('app_test_form', array('start_date' => '2016-01-04T16:01:25+0000')), 'items' => array()), array()) 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php at line 282   + 
at Controller ->createForm ('app_test_form', array('start_date' => '2016-01-04T16:01:25+0000')), 'items' => array())) 
in src/AppBundle/Controller/DummyController.php at line 39   +
```

Comment: Do you have php5-intl extension ?

Comment: Did you actually try the `format` option? Please note that the view data is both the data that is shown to the user as well as the data entered by the user. If you use your form in an API, the view data is the data sent by the consumer of your API.

Comment: @xabbuh i understand except that the model transformer get triggered first and it triggers the error please check the symfony code

Comment: Looks like something is going wrong for you then. When does the model transformer get triggered with the wrong data? When the form is created or when the request is submitted? And can you show the complete stack trace of that error?

Comment: @xabbuh when the form is created

Comment: Why do you pass the formatted date string instead of a `DateTime` object to the form?

Comment: thats based on my use case and as i understand it should be completely correct right ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you also need to add **format**

Refer details [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/date.html#reference-forms-type-date-format)

> wondering if thats the desired behavior or an issue

This seems to be behaviour as per documentation, refer [line 140](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php#L140)

```
// Change the input to a HTML5 date input if
    //  * the widget is set to "single_text"

    //  * the format matches the one expected by HTML5

    //  * the html5 is set to true


add('start_date', 'date', array(
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'c'))
```

refer [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185097/symfony2-datetime-field-form)

Comment: this is a `view` format rather than a `model` format

Answer (score 0):

```
$builder->add('start_date', 'datetime', array(
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'input'  => 'string',
        'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss'
    ));
```

try this one, hope will help full to you

Comment: both `format` and `date_format` options will work on the view data rather than the input data.